# Socket programming in client and server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I have an error in a client file

```
bash-4.2# gcc -lm -pthread cliente.c -o cliente

cliente.c: In function ‘main’:

cliente.c:25:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
[enabled by default]memset(&addr.sin_zero,0,sizeof(addr.sin_zero));

cliente.c:47:12: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default] mensagem[strlen(mensagem)-1] = '\0';
```

Below the code:

```
include stdio.h 
include sys/types.h
include sys/socket.h
include netinet/in.h
include arpa/inet.h
include netdb.h

int main() {
int    meu_socket;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

meu_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

if (meu_socket == -1) {
  printf("Erro ao criar o socket!\n");
  return 1;
}

addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port        = htons(5555);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

memset(&addr.sin_zero,0,sizeof(addr.sin_zero));

printf("Tentando se conectar ao servidor...\n");

if (connect(meu_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
  printf("Erro ao se conectar!\n");
  return 1;
}

printf("Conectado!\n\n");

int recebidos, enviados; 
char mensagem[256];
char resposta[256];

do {

    /* O processo inverso é feito aqui. Como o servidor espera uma mensagem inicialmente, o cliente deverá fornecê-la */

    printf("Cliente: ");

    fgets(mensagem,256,stdin);
    mensagem[strlen(mensagem)-1] = '\0';

    enviados = send(meu_socket,mensagem,strlen(mensagem),0);

    /* Após enviar a mensagem, espera-se a resposta do servidor */

    recebidos = recv(meu_socket,resposta,256,0);
    resposta[recebidos] = '\0';

    printf("Servidor: %s\n",resposta);

  } while(recebidos != -1 && enviados != -1);


  close(meu_socket);         
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've applied code formatting to your code, but it's still missing the `#` in front of your `include`s. No sure how you lost them.  Also, Stack Overflow is presented in English.

Comment: Try again in http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: copilar? in Portuguese it is compilar !

Comment: Can we either mark my answer as accepted, or delete this question altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

`string.h` is where the prototypes for `memset` and `strlen` are.